# Extrair HTML do Inspecionar Elemento

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Usando HtmlAgilityPack, uso o seguinte código para pegar o HTML de um site:

```
var url = "teste.com";
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(url);
```

Porém os dados (uma tabela) que quero extrair do site, aparece apenas no inspecionar elemento do navegador e não no código-fonte...
Como posso pegar todo conteudo do inspecionar elemento?

Comment: Já verificou se ela não está em um iframe da página? Acho que o ideal seria termos mais informações.

Comment: Aqui está o código-fonte que meu código obtêm https://pastebin.com/j7rix872
(Eu acho que tem javascript envolvido, será que isso influência?)

Comment: Sim, influencia, alguns dos conteúdos podem ser inseridos posteriormente com javascript. O ideal é que você mapeasse as requisições e visse se alguma delas após a requisição da página está pegando essas informações. Vou passar como exemplo o site checkerproxy.net que parece ser parecido ou até mesmo o que você esta usando, ao olhar na aba network aqui do chrome mesmo eu vi que ele faz uma requisicao que retorna a pagina e em seguida uma outra que retorna um json com os dados pra preencher em seguida.

Comment: Há como pegar esses dados? Estou tentando e não obtive progresso

Comment: Sim, claro, mas para isso precisaria entender a forma como você está tentando pegar, se for por exemplo via httprequest seria uma questão de alterar o endpoint em que você está batendo que a resposta ia ser o que você quer.

Comment: Fui clicando pra lá e pra cá na aba network, visto que eu não conhecia ela antes, e acabei encontrando o site https://checkerproxy.net/api/archive/2018-09-06

Comment: De forma simples, esse link contém o que preciso

Comment: Obrigado, isso resolveu meu problema...